# Converting from Javascript to Typescript, Knockout and DevExtreme controls

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, devextreme

I am having some issues converting from Javascript to Typescript and in particular the creation of a devextreme control.

In the past I would create an object in my viewmodel for the devextreme controls using something like this:

```
self.myButton = {
  text: 'Click Me',
  disabled: ko.purecomputed(function(){ return self.myobservable().length>0;});
}
```

Which works well, in typescript I tried...

```
myButton: DevExpress.ui.dxButtonOptions;
```

Then in the constructor...

```
....
self.myButton = {
  text: 'Click Me',
  disabled: ko.purecomputed(function(){ return self.myobservable().length>0;});
}
...
```

Which gives me an error Type KnockoutComputed is not assignable to type boolean, which is fair enough, I get this.

But the question is how should this be done?

I can just use this:

```
myButton: any;
```

In the declaration of the button options, but I think that kinda defeats the purpose of using typescript??

This can work, one of the reasons for going to typescript was to also use things like webpack etc, so it's not a total loss, I'd just like to know how to do this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One idea: You can try to use `keyof` and extends the `DevExpress` interfaces to take `KnockoutComputed<T> & T` as value.

Comment: As an option you can use [knockout-decorator](https://github.com/gnaeus/knockout-decorators) for your properties. In that case properties will have simple type and could be use for DevExtreme's options.

Comment: @unional Can you give me any example on how to use the keyof with a devexpress interface, I am new to typescript, so no idea on where to start?

Comment: @mykhailo.romaniuk thanks for the link to this, I have never seen this, but it certainly looks good.
One question though, if I were to do this, would I have to break my pureComputed into a seperate method of the vm?

Comment: @JasonColey I have played a bit with [knockout-decorators](https://github.com/gnaeus/knockout-decorators) and it seems that they won't resolve your issue. Also I had thoughts about using [knockout-es5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5), but all solutions for your problem with this lib also looks like workaround for me. I have to say that I don't see better way than using _any_ for widget options

Comment: I will post my researches so you just can decide by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked possibilities to use [knockout-decorators](https://github.com/gnaeus/knockout-decorators) and [knockout-es5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5) to resolve your issue. However I think that the most cleaner way would be to simply use *any* as type of your widget options.

Template for both examples is the same:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: buttonOptions"></div>
```

### Using knockout-es5

This approach require creating computed property separately. Creation of this property isn't well typed, so we are loosing some of strong typing benefits here.

```
// importing thing from DevExtreme.
import "devextreme/ui/button";
import DevExpress from "devextreme/bundles/dx.all";

import * as ko from "knockout";
// importing knockout-es5 to include track and defineProperty functionality
import "knockout-es5";

// This small util will make creation of compute a bit more strong by using keyof
const createComputed = <T>(prototype: T, key: keyof T, computedFunc: Function): void => {
    ko.defineProperty(prototype, key, computedFunc);
}

class DevextremeTestViewModel {
    clickCounter: number = 0;
    buttonOptions: DevExpress.ui.dxButtonOptions;

    constructor() {
        this.buttonOptions = {
            text: "Start",
            onClick: this.increaseCounter
        };

        // start tracking clickCounter property (make it observable)
        ko.track(this, ["clickCounter"]);

        // assign to text property of widget options computed value
        createComputed(this.buttonOptions, "text", () => {
            return `Clicked ${this.clickCounter} times`;
        });
    }

    increaseCounter(): void {
        this.clickCounter++;
    }
}
```

### Using knockout-decorators

This approach require creating computed property separately (as part of viewModel). Also it's require "hack" with copying getter of computed property to widget options:

```
import "devextreme/ui/button";
import DevExpress from "devextreme/bundles/dx.all";
// include required decorators
import { observable, computed } from "knockout-decorators";

// Magic function to copy getter from one property to another
const copyGetter = <T, TProp>(prototype: T, key: keyof T, propProto: TProp, propertyKey: keyof TProp) => {
    let getter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(propProto, propertyKey).get;
    Object.defineProperty(prototype, key, {
        get: getter
    });
}

class DevextremeTestViewModel {
    // Create observable
    @observable clickCounter: number = 0;
    // Create computed that based on observable
    @computed({ pure: true }) get buttonText(): string {
        return `Clicked ${this.clickCounter} times`;
    };
    buttonOptions: DevExpress.ui.dxButtonOptions;

    constructor() {
        this.buttonOptions = {
            text: this.buttonText,
            onClick: this.increaseCounter
        };

        // Need to copy getter from our computed to options property.
        copyGetter(this.buttonOptions, "text", this, "buttonText");
    }

    increaseCounter(): void {
        this.clickCounter++;
    }
}
```

## Using *any*

As I said, since we cannot force DevExtreme team to change interface of widget's options to support `T | KnockoutObservable<T> | KncokoutComputed<T>`, the most "cleaner" way for me - use *any*:

```
import "devextreme/ui/button";
import DevExpress from "devextreme/bundles/dx.all";
import { observable, computed } from "knockout-decorators";
import * as ko from "knockout";

class DevextremeTestViewModel {
    // Create observable
    @observable clickCounter: number = 0;
    buttonOptions: any = {
        text: ko.pureComputed(()=> {
            return `Clicked ${this.clickCounter} times`;
        }),
        onClick: this.increaseCounter
    };

    increaseCounter(): void {
        this.clickCounter++;
    }
}
```